# Allow GridView cell's height to expand but maintain same height for all cells

Tags: android, gridview

In Android, I have a GridView where each "cell" within the GridView has an ImageView and below the ImageView a TextView. The width of the cell is always fixed for all cells. The image is fixed in size and is the same for all cells. The text however can vary in length. When the length of the text is wider than the cell's width, the text wraps and the cell's height should expand to keep the entire text visible.

The problem I am having is that I cannot seem to get the height on all the cells to be the same. If one cell has little text (with no wrapping) but the cell adjacent to it has enough to cause wrapping, the height of first cell is shorter than the adjacent one. It would be nice if the cells had the same height and the textview grew in height.

Here's my xml for the GridView:

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gvDevices"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/llToolbar"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:columnWidth="160dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="5dp" >
```

And here's the xml for each cell:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/GridItem"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/image_border"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivDevice"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCaption"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#707070"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Huawei, 2013-05-29 6:30 PM"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT**
I came across this post:
[How can I stretch the cells of the GridView vertically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11843192/how-can-i-stretch-the-cells-of-the-gridview-vertically?rq=1)

But the solution isn't correct. I don't want a fixed number of lines in the TextView.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is you can set both maxLines and minLines to same value. Then each cell will be of same height :)

Answer (score -1):

Personally, when i want to keep the same height for Gridview items, i set Maxlines to 1 for Child TextView and i set a fixed height for child Container.

in your exemple :

- add **android:maxLines="1"** to tvCaption
- add **android:minHeight="X dip"** and **android:layout_height="X dip"** to GridItem

Replace X with a sufficient value.

Comment: But that doesn't allow the height to stretch with increased text, which is what I requested.

Comment: just make a fixed height for grid item

Comment: -1: It doesn't solve the issue. Setting fixed height is definitly not a good idea, we want to adapt our views depending of its content, properly.

Comment: @AndroidDev had asked for a fixed size so I've answered exactly about what he needed. please don't downvote if your request is different. other guys may need that.

Comment: "The text however can vary in length" => It's not a fixed size at all ! The height of all cells have to be the same, but it's a dynamic height depending of the content. So definitly, it's NOT answering to the question.
Moreover, I want to see well written code when I have to maintain it, so I downvote answer that are not flexible at all. From my point of view, it's a very bad practise what you are doing.